# how to increase or decreas the classes of the legend?

Tags: r

The code given bellow will plot the image of a binary file.the problem is that most of the values are within 1 to 3000  but the classes of the legend are like this: 0 to 2000  and 2000 t 4000 and 4000 to 6000.so all values  lower than 2000 have the same colour.how can I increase the classes? for example : 1 to 300 then 300 to 600 then 600 to 900  etc....

```
library(fields)
t<- file("C:annual_Prc2000_without999_1.img","rb")
 e=readBin(t, double(), size=4,n=720*360, signed=TRUE)
 y<-matrix(data=e,ncol=360,nrow=720)
image.plot(t(t(y)),main="Annual prcipitation_2000 _mm/yr ", add = FALSE,
 legend.shrink = 0.9, legend.width = 1.2, legend.mar = NULL, graphics.reset = FALSE,
horizontal = FALSE, bigplot = NULL, smallplot = NULL, legend.only = FALSE, lab.breaks=NULL,
 axis.args=NULL, ylim=c(1,0))
```

Comment: Copying from the help page: "One can also include a breaks argument for an unequal color scale with color scale boundaries at the breaks (see example below)."

Comment: Continuing to read the help page to you  ... look for: "# adding breaks and distinct colors for intervals of z
# with and without lab.breaks".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a worked example modified slightly from the help page:

```
 x<- 1:10; y<- 1:15; z<- outer( x,y,"+") 
 brk<- quantile( c(z), probs=(0:10)/10 )
 image.plot(x,y,z, breaks=brk, col=rainbow(10))
```